# Big-O Notation & Legendre Symbol

Tags: number-theory

Why the following equality is true if we let N to infinity;

$\sum _{m>\sqrt{N}}\frac{1}{m}(\frac{d}{m}) = O(\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}})$ , where  $(\frac{d}{m})$  is Jacobi Symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is the tail of a Dirichlet series, and the Jacobi symbol is a non-principal Dirichlet character, so the associated $L$-function $L(\chi,s)$ is converging at $s=1$ and the claim:
$$ \sum_{n>N}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}=O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right) $$
follows by summation by parts. By the Polya-Vinogradov's or Burgess' inequality we also have that the absolute value of the sum of the values of the Jacobi symbol over an interval is substantially smaller than the length $L$ of the interval, provided that $L$ is big enough. So I bet the previous line can be improved up to:
$$ \sum_{n>N}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}=O\left(\frac{\log^2 N}{N^{3/2}}\right). $$

Comment: How do you do with summation by parts, I couldn't follow.